Trying to pip install a beets plugin on Win11, but missing dependency
I'm using
pip install "beets[replaygain]" 

but I keep getting this error:
..\meson.build:31:9: ERROR: 
Dependency 'gobject-introspection-1.0' is required but not found

How can I install this dependency on Windows 11?
I've tried installing it with MSYS2, and I now have some directories called 'gobject-introspection-1.0'. I've tried adding them to my PATH, but I must be doing something wrong because they aren't fixing the problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

I got this error before.
You need to install GTK Development Tools to solve it.

I tried installing GTK4, GTK3, and python-gobject  from gtk.org with msys2, but it didn't seem to help. It seems to have installed Ok, and I see the folders but pip can't find it.

Maybe it is something related to where pip is running.
Was pip installed for the user or the whole system?
Some such problems arise in Windows environments, so using Conda is better on Windows.
